# raspberry piでシャットダウン時、リブート時にスクリプトを実行したい。

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 3 model Bを使って、シャットダウン時・リブート時に簡単なスクリプトを実行したいのですが、スクリプトが実行された形跡がなく嵌っています。

スクリプトの内容は "test" という文字列をファイルに書き出すだけのスクリプトです。期待値は、シャットダウンあるいはリブートをしたら、ログファイルが生成されるというのが期待値なのですが、ファイルが生成されていないため、スクリプトが実行されていないと判断しました。

ちなみに、ターミナルを起動し、以下のスクリプトを実行した場合は、所望の動作をしました。サービスの登録の仕方に問題があるのではと考えています。

ディストリビューションは、Ubuntu 16.04です。

スクリプトの内容は、以下の通りです。
以下のリンクを参考にしました。

[Linuxでシャットダウン時に想定した処理が実行されない - Qiita](https://qiita.com/toshihirock/items/4c8c3987b8837989d6fb)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
name="test"
lock_file="/var/lock/subsys/${name}"
log_file="/var/log/${name}.log"
echo ${name} >> ${log_file}

start(){
    touch ${lock_file}
    #他のスクリプトを呼び出す処理(現在はコメントアウト中)
}
stop(){
    rm -f ${lock_file}
}
case "${1}" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
     *)
        echo "Usage: ${0} {start|stop|restart}"
     ;;
esac
```

やったことは以下の通りです。

- /etc/init.d/の中に上記スクリプト(test)を置きました。
- /etc/rc0.d/と/etc/rc6.d/の中にシンボリックリンク(S00test)を作成しました。
- test/S00testの権限は実行可能状態になっています。
- sysv-rc-confコマンドでtestをランレベル0と6でスタートするようにしました。

  ```
  $ sysv-rc-conf --list
  test 0:on    6:on
  ```
- さらに、/var/lock/subsys/の中にもtestを置きました。

ちゃんと理解できておらずお恥ずかしい限りです。
もし、同じような経験をされた方、解決策をご教示いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 の `/etc/init.d/rc` スクリプトを見ると、`/var/lock/subsys/` ディレクトリ内のファイルをチェックしていませんね。ところで、シンボリックリンクファイルの名前を `K00test` にするとどうなりますでしょうか。

Comment: コマンドラインから直接スクリプトを実行した場合はどうなるでしょうか。また、既存のスクリプトを覗くと必ず`exit n`の形式で終了ステータスを明示してexitしていますが、今回の例だとそれが無いのが気になります。

Comment: 理解が足りず具体的には書けませんが、Ubuntu 16.04の場合、systemd が使われるので起動停止時のコマンド実行は作法が異なる気がします。 `poweroff.target` 辺りを調べてみると分かるかもしれません。

Comment: S00testからK00testにしてみましたが、症状は変わりませんでした。コマンドラインから直接スクリプトを実行した場合は問題なく動作をしています。仮にスクリプトの最終行にexit 0と記載してみましたが、動作は変わりませんでした。systemdに関する情報を調べてみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 既にコメントにもあるけど`init.d`じゃなくて`systemd`じゃだめなの？

Comment: cronの@reboot使うのが早そう(今行き当たっている問題の直接的な解決にはならないのでコメント)

Answer (score 0):

> さらに、/var/lock/subsys/の中にもtestを置きました。

/var/lock/subsys/{$name}はスクリプトが起動していることを示すロックファイルですので、これが存在するとすでにスクリプトが実行中とみなされ起動されません。

```
start(){
    touch ${lock_file}
```

ここで作成しているので自分で作成する必要はありません。

Comment: /var/lock/subsys/の中にtestを置かずにやってもみましたが、症状は変わりませんでした。引き続き調査を進めます。

Answer (score 0):

crontab に@rebootを使ってスクリプトを実行するようにしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
$ echo '@reboot /path/to/script' | crontab
$ crontab -l
@reboot /path/to/script

Debian CRONTAB(5)
-----
string         meaning
------         -------
@reboot        Run once, at startup.
@yearly        Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
@annually      (same as @yearly)
@monthly       Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
@weekly        Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
@daily         Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
@midnight      (same as @daily)
@hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
```

参考資料
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-ja/crontab.5.ja.html